# Why the scene DontDestroyOnLoad is staying when switchig back to main menu?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is that when I hit escape to go baco to main menu then I have the dont destroy objects original on the main menu and also the same objects in the DontDestroyOnLoad scene.

I have in the main menu scene 3 objects Player, Game Manager, Scene Loader that each one have attached a script DontDestroy :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DontDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        if (GameManager.backToMainMenu == false)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(transform);
        }
    }
}
```

In the Game Manager object also attached another script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SceneLoader sceneLoader;
    public PlayerController playerController;
    public CamMouseLook camMouseLook;
    public static bool backToMainMenu = false;
    public static bool togglePauseGame;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            PauseGame();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            BackToMainMenu();
        }
    }

    public void PauseGame()
    {
        togglePauseGame = !togglePauseGame;

        if (togglePauseGame == true)
        {
            playerController.enabled = false;
            camMouseLook.enabled = false;
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
        }
        else
        {
            playerController.enabled = true;
            camMouseLook.enabled = true;
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
        }
    }

    private void BackToMainMenu()
    {
        sceneLoader.LoadScene(0);
        playerController.enabled = false;
        camMouseLook.enabled = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        backToMainMenu = true;
    }
}
```

When I press the escape key it's switching scenes between 1 and 0 and loading scene 0 the main menu.
But then the result is this :

[image: Back to main menu]

So I pressed escape and back to main menu but the DontDestroyOnLoad also still loaded not removed so I have this 3 objects Player, Game Manager, Scene Loader duplicated.

If I will click on new game again the main menu scene will be remove so there will be no duplication but when back to main menu the DontDestroyOnLoad is stay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) it's supposed to do, preserve a GameObject across multiple scenes. Your `GameManager` script starts with `backToMainMenu` stetted to `false`, which will trigger the execution of `DontDestroyOnLoad` on the `Awake` function the first time, but not the second (since, when you go back to the main menu, `backToMainMenu` is setted to `true`).

Comment: So it's not a problem that there are duplicated objects ? I thought that it will make some performance problems. Thanks.

Comment: Overtime, having multiple copies of the same GameObject will cause performance issues. If you don't wanna duplicate copies (but one single instance of each) you can use a [Singleton](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjpsZrKvuzoAhUFx4sKHYmTC1oQwqsBMAN6BAgKEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DCPKAgyp8cno&usg=AOvVaw2O3anSuaVcdMqyyhmSGhip) pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, the objects will persists across loading of scenes. That means if there are some already in a scene to begin with there will be multiple ones after loading / reloading a scene.

I deal with by making an `Init` class & object in every scene, which checks a static variable, and instantiates the objects that are supposed to persist. That way you can start the game from every scene.

```
class Init {
  public static bool hasInstantiatedController = false;
  public GameObject GameController;

  void Awake() {
   if (!hasInstantiatedController) {
     hasInstantiatedController = true;
     Instantiate (GameController, transform.position, transform.rotation);
   }
  }
}
```